# Fill Datalist in vb6

Tags: vb6

I am new to vb6 since I always use vb2010. I am debugging an inventory software running in vb6 and couldn't find out how to fill datalist control using recordset.

The software use this code, it uses listbox...

```
with rs

    if .RecordCount then
          .MoveLast
          .MoveFirst
          For Counter=1 to .RecordCount
              Me.ListBox1.AddItem rs!ProductName
              .MoveNext
          Next
     End If
     .Close

End With
```

---

But the software database has now thousand of products and the program loads the data so slow
so I tried this:

```
Using Datalist

With DataList1
    Set .RowSource = rs
    .ListField = "ProductName"
End With
```

my code runs with no errors but no data will appear in the control.

Can anyone solve this problem for me.
thank you in advance

Comment: The old code loads the data correctly and yours don't.  You may make it little faster using some batch loading tricks.  A quick solution is to ask yourself the question, is it necessary to load all products into memory?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `MoveLast` call which iterates over the entire recordset solely for the purpose of populating `RecordCount`. Use this instead:

```
With rs
    Do While Not rs.eof
         Me.ListBox1.AddItem rs!ProductName
         .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
```

This code will speed up your call by removing the unnecessary traversing of the recordset, but having thousands of items in a listbox is a design/usability issue that speeding the load will not fix.